# Sum up the array values

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, sum

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array( [0] => Array( [value] => 25 ) )
    [1] => Array( [0] => Array( [value] => 75 ) )
    [2] => Array( [0] => Array( [value] => 10 ) )
    [3] => Array( [0] => Array( [value] => 10 ) )
)
```

I am working on a custom module in drupal and need to sum up the [value],
However I tried different approaches using array_column, array_sum, but didn't get the solution.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Code

```
$contributionDetails = $node->get('field_contributions')->getValue();              
foreach ( $contributionDetails as $element ) {
    $p = Paragraph::load( $element['target_id'] );
    $text[] = $p->field_contribution_percentage->getValue();             
}
```

Comment: What is the desired output ?

Comment: How are these values generated?

Comment: Did you start with a loop maintaining an accumulator?#

Comment: `$contributionDetails = $node->get('field_contributions')->getValue();

            foreach ( $contributionDetails as $element ) {
                $p = Paragraph::load( $element['target_id'] );
                $text[] = $p->field_contribution_percentage->getValue();
            }`

$text returns the above array..
@NigelRen

Comment: Desired output is total sum of `[value]` colum. @executable

Comment: So in that `foreach()` loop, just add up the values of `$p->field_contribution_percentage->getValue()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `array_map` here instead of an accumulator:

```php
$arraySum = array_map(function ($v) {
  return reset($v)['value'];
}, $text);

print_r(array_sum($arraySum)); // 120
```

**Edit**, as a full example:

```php
$values = [
    [['value' => 25]],
    [['value' => 75]],
    [['value' => 10]],
    [['value' => 10]],
];

echo array_sum(array_map(function ($v) {
  return reset($v)['value'];
}, $values)); // 120
```

Comment: Most elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

A couple of loops and an accumulator is one way to achieve this

```
$tot = 0;
foreach ($array as $a){
    foreach ($a as $b){
        $tot += $b['value'];
    }
}
echo $tot;
```

Or if you are sure there will always only be one occurance of the inner array.

```
$tot = 0;
foreach ($array as $a){
    $tot += $a[0]['value'];
}
echo $tot;
```

Or using the code you just posted

```
$contributionDetails = $node->get('field_contributions')->getValue();              
$tot = 0;
foreach ( $contributionDetails as $element ) {
    $p = Paragraph::load( $element['target_id'] );
    $text[] = $p->field_contribution_percentage->getValue();
    $tot += $p->field_contribution_percentage->getValue();
}
echo $tot;
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have an array containing 2 arrays which have the index 'value', you just need to loop each array using nested foreach and a variable `$sum` which sum up the value on each iteration.

Try this code:

```
<?php 

$sum = 0;
foreach($array as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $v){
        $sum += $v['value'];
    }
}

echo $sum;
```

This will output 120

Comment: Thank you, Indeed it is 120. Appreciated